# Selenium with JavaScript and Nodejs: How to count elements on page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with Javascript (NodeJS) and I need to count some elements by CSS selector.

I tried several approaches:

```
client.findElements(By.css(".some-class")).size();
```

It gives me:
`Uncaught TypeError: client.findElements(...).size is not a function`

```
client.findElements(By.css(".some-class")).Count();
```

It gives me:
`Uncaught TypeError: client.findElements(...).size is not a function`

```
client.findElements(By.css(".some-class")).length;
```

Here `length` is always undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findElements` returns a promise that will resolve to an array of WebElements.

```
client.findElements(By.css(".some-class")).then(elements => console.log(elements.length));
```

Comment: Thanks :) ... I'm not using ES6, but still I got the idea, tried it and now all's fine :)